# Greasemonkey functions don't work in my script?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I can't get my Greasemonkey script to work...

```
GM_registerMenuCommand("What's My IP Address?", function(){

GM_xmlhttpRequest({
    method: "GET",
    url: "http://tools.ip2location.com/ib2",
    onerror: function(oEvent){ alert("Error " + oEvent.target.status + " occurred while receiving the document."); },
    onload: function(response){
        if (response.readyState !== 4 || response.status !== 200) return;
        // we can parse now
        var myregexp = /<a[^>]*>([\s\S]*?(?:Your IP Address)[\s\S]*?)<\/a>/i;
        var match = myregexp.exec(response.responseText);
        if (match != null) {
            // got match
            subject = match[1];
            // format first line
            subject_2 = subject.replace(/<br><b>/mg, " ");
            // remove html
            subject_3 = subject_2.replace(/<\/?[a-z][a-z0-9]*[^<>]*>|<!--[\s\S]*?-->/ig, "");
            // now remove whitespaces
            result = subject_3.replace(/^[ \s]*/mg, "");
        } else {
            // no match, error
            result = "I couldn't find your IP Address :(";
        }
        alert(result);
    }
});

});

(function(){

})();
```

Nothing happens with `GM_registerMenuCommand`.

I can throw an alert so I know the script is running, but how do I run `GM_registerMenuCommand`?

Comment: Your script is running fine for me. It displays my IP/ISP/country etc in an alert in Firefox just fine.

Comment: hmm i dont understand what Im doing wrong.. you used it just as it is?

Comment: Had to add some metatags only. Uploaded to jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9Wp4D/

Comment: Oh I also added the `var` keyword to before some undeclared vars and removed the empty IIFE at the end which has no effect, it is also missing the @grant metatag but it should run nevertheless.

Comment: Had to @grant xmlhttpRequest  in meta - thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of version 2.0, Greasemonkey now defaults to `@grant none`.

You have to explicitly add `@grant GM_xmlhttpRequest` to the userscript metadata block, otherwise `GM_xmlhttpRequest` won't be available to your userscript.

```
// ==UserScript==
[...]
// @grant GM_registerMenuCommand
// @grant GM_xmlhttpRequest
// ==/UserScript==
```